# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (z^{n} + z^{n+1})=1$ for all $z$ in the interior of the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a little trouble with this.

> Prove that, for all $|z|$ < 1 we have: $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (z^{n} + z^{n+1})=1.$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: That all of this equals 1. Sorry :)

Comment: Did you try to compute the partial sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (z^{n} + z^{n+1})=(1+z)-(z+z^2)+...=1+(-1)^n \lim_{n\to \infty} z^{n+1} =1\pm 0=1 $. Note that we need the condition $|z|<1$ for the limit.

Comment: Why did you used the $\pm lim_{n \to \infty} z^n$?

Comment: Actually, as it would be zero, I did not care about the sign. However, I edited the answer now.

Comment: @LoryVeri As I am starting here from today!, it would be nice if you confirm my answer or up vote it, if you found it correct or helpful.

Comment: I did. Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Nice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^n(z^n+z^{n+1})=1+(-1)^kz^{k+1}.$$

It's a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: These are infinite geometric series. Split the sum into two terms.
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z)^n=\frac{1}{1+z}$ and $z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z)^n=z\frac{1}{1+z}$.

$\frac{1}{1+z}+z\frac{1}{1+z}=1$